# How to get MAX from Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the `MAX` from a database but I am trying two methods, and need to be cleared if both methods are correct or not.

**These are my Object types:**

```
Emp_t (eno: number(4), ename: varchar2(15), edept: ref dept_t, salary: number(8,2))
Dept_t (dno: number(2), dname: varchar2(12), mgr ref emp_t)
Proj_t (pno: number(4), pname: varchar2(15), pdept ref dept_t, budget: number(10,2))
```

**And these are my Tables:**

```
Emp of Emp_t (eno primary key, edept references dept)
Dept of Dept_t (dno primary key, mgr references emp)
Proj of Proj_t (pno primary key, pdept references dept)
```

My question is:

**Q.) Find the manager’s name who is controlling the project with the largest budget**

My first answer is:

```
SELECT p.pdept.mgr.ename
FROM proj p
WHERE p.budget IN (SELECT MAX(p.budget) FROM proj p)
```

And my second answer is:

```
SELECT p.pdept.mgr.ename, MAX(p.budget)
FROM proj p
```

**I need to know which answer is correct. or both are right. If one is incorrect the reason for that?**

Comment: They are supposed to look `like this` just to emphasize the words

Comment: Have you run either query? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You need `join`s.  In the most recent versions of Oracle, a simple method uses `order by` and `fetch`:

```
select e.name
from proj_t p join
     emp_t e
     on p.mgr = e.eno join
     dept_t d
     on p.pdept = d.dno
order by p.budget desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

The key point is that you need to use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I just only need to know if my two answers are right or wrong.

Comment: @JananathBanuka . . . Do they have `join`?  No.  They are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your queries are right.

**Issue with 1st Query -**

```
SELECT p.pdept.mgr.ename        ----- This is not the correct syntax
FROM proj p
WHERE p.budget IN (SELECT MAX(p.budget) FROM proj p)
```

The syntax is not correct for select clause. The syntax should be -

```
SELECT e.name
FROM proj_t p 
INNER JOIN emp_t e ON p.mgr = e.eno
INNER JOIN dept_t d ON p.pdept = d.dno
WHERE p.budget = (SELECT MAX(budget) FROM proj_t);
```

**Issue with 2nd Query -**

```
SELECT p.pdept.mgr.ename, MAX(p.budget)   -----  You cannot use other columns with aggregate function without group by clause.
FROM proj p
```

Please use the above query and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use MAX or limit the output by one row:

```
SELECT p.pdept.mgr.ename
FROM proj p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM proj subp
    WHERE subp.budget > p.budget
)
```

This will search for a higher `budet` in `proj` untill there is none.